# iOS: UIScrollView with horizontal scrolling of 2 images

Tags: ios, iphone, scrollview

I am working on an app in which I will get data from server and I need to display images in scrollview with horizontal scrolling. I have done that previously showing single image with content of that image and horizontal scrolling. However I am not getting, how should we achieve showing 2 images in horizontal scroll. Any kind of help and suggestion would be really great help thanks.[image]

Comment: you should follow MVC architecture just like UITableView  with proper delegates and datasource so that view controller can provide its data to your component and the component can populate itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work for you.

```
int x = 0;
int imgW = self.galleryScrollView.frame.size.width/2;
int imgH = self.galleryScrollView.frame.size.height;

NSArray *imagesURL = @[@"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/66/16/7f/66167f56c01bbcbdf32d68ceb414135a.jpg", @"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/66/16/7f/66167f56c01bbcbdf32d68ceb414135a.jpg", @"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/66/16/7f/66167f56c01bbcbdf32d68ceb414135a.jpg"];
NSInteger count = imagesURL.count;
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, imgW, imgH)];
    NSString *imgURL = imagesURL[i];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]]];
    [self.galleryScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    x = x + imgW;
}
self.galleryScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, self.galleryScrollView.frame.size.height);
```